# Several angular modules for routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Can i create several modules for routing in AngularJS app like:

**1. First route management file:**

```
    angular.module('app.p.routes', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/forbidden',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/forbidden.html'
            })
        .......................
```

**2. Second route management file:**

```
     angular.module('app.admin.routes', ['ngRoute'])

      .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        .when('/admin-dashboard',
            {
                templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/admin/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashboardController',
                controllerAs: 'dashboard'
            })
        .............................
```

**3. Main app file:**

```
    angular.module('mainApp',
    [
        'ngAnimate',          //animating
        'app.p.routes',         //public routing
        'app.admin.routes',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngParallax',          //parallax effect
        'ngFileUpload'
    ])
```

When i tried to use this approach page hangs and angular throws error:

```
> VM188:30554 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

I need an approach to split public and admin routing management.

Comment: Maybe you are including your route file more than once and the module gets declared multiple times. How do you access the route? With /#/admin-dashboard? Could you provide us a plunkr or a jsbin?

Comment: We have it split out like that and it works fine. When I've seen that error, it's because a template URL was pointing to a place where there wasn't a file.

Comment: Plunker :https://plnkr.co/edit/qFlZ2e?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many AngularJS modules as you like. There are no rules against that, however, you've attempted to include the Angular source twice which is why you're seeing this warning...

`> VM188:30554 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

---

The simplest solution to your issue that I can think of, is to add an event listener to the `$routeChangeStart` event. With this you'll be able to verify that the current user has the correct permissions to view anything before they actually to do so.

A simple Service to store some basic information on the current user could like this.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.service('AuthenticationService', function () {
  // Set the User object
  this.setUser = function () {
    this.$user = user;
  };

  // Get the User object
  this.getUser = function (user) {
    return this.$user
  };
});
```

And then upon receiving the `$routeChangeStart` event, you can retrieve the user object and confirm that they are allowed to proceed to the chosen resource.

Here's an example, whereupon a user needs to be an Administrator to view any route that has "/admin" in it.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
  // Create a listener for the "$routeChangeStart" event
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
    // Is the user is an Administrator? Are they attempting to access a restricted route?
    if ($location.url().indexOf('/admin') && !AuthenticationService.getUser().isAdmin) {
      // Redirect the user to the login page
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  });
});
```

---

If you want a more advanced solution however, have a look at this: https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission

This will enable you to achieve a more in-depth ACL implementation across your application.